# Add a class to a sharepoint web part project

Tags: web-part, development

I do apoligize in advance for that's a probably silly question but... I'm developing a custom Sharepoint Webpart and, for the sake os SOLID principle, I need to embed certain functionalities in separate class files. Except from creating a class library is it possible to embed a class into the webpart project and use it into webpart's class?

Answer (score 2):

No, in SharePoint development you should repeat blocks of code in each monolithic web part class.

ONLY KIDDING!

Yes, it is a good practice to have shared generic classes for your web parts, feature receivers, etc. Another good idea is to have your own base web part class to derive from.

Comment: I'm not able to cast an up vote for you but thank you very much! :)

Comment: Give a tick. Only the questioner can do this.